# How to detect Android version and brand from webkit browser?

Tags: android

How to detect Android version and brand via webkit browser and is it reliable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could check for the user agent.

However, I don't think it's safe since there are many method that one can use to spoof the user agent.

Searching Google on that issue gives us lots of answers on that. It works even on the default browser... you just type "`about:debug`" as address, and then a debug option `UAString` comes up in the settings, allowing you to change that to iPhone and other stuff.

Of course, with a proper 3rd party app, I'd guess the sky is the limit.

*edit: my Nexus S shows this as of now:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.6; pt-br; Nexus S Build/GRK39F) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

Comment: THanks! I see you are from Brazil too.

Comment: Yes! :-) Are you from here? Anyway... I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about:debug, I was trying to get extra info by doing about:version and getting nowhere fast.