# Get Android version at server side using ASP.Net

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, mobile-website

I am trying to detect the android version of the Android, like 2.2 ... 4.0. I am developing a web app in Asp.Net 4.0 MVC 3.0 C#.I have tried with the `HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase` class. How can I achive this?
All ideas are appreciated.
Thank you All.

Comment: Did you come across [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8073800/1101070) question in your research?

Comment: @Marvin Pinto Yes I came upon the question, however it doesnot speak about doing it from server side code.Thank you

Comment: Fair enough, I just wanted to point that out in case you were unsure about the client side since you didn't really mention that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check the value of [HttpRequest.UserAgent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent.aspx).

It looks like if you check the [user agent values](http://www.gtrifonov.com/2011/04/15/google-android-user-agent-strings-2/) from that property, it should contain "Android 2.2", "Android 3.0" and so on.

Comment: How can the versions be differtiated? If one feature needs to be supported on Android 2.1 to 4.0, how can this be achieved? I do not want to create any array of the range.

Comment: socialCircus - not an area i've dealt with in relation to mobiles, but would modernizer not help with some of these compatability issues without recourse to switch/case statements as it would downscale the capabilities if html5 features weren't supported etc

Comment: @socialCircus extracting the exact information from the user agent string is up to you and could be done with a regex or a substring.  Why you're trying to check the UA on the server side rather than discover browser capabilities on the view is a bit beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

taken from the mvcmobile nuget template, a means of determining if we're looking at a mobile device. you could edit/refactor to suit:

```
public static bool IsSupportedMobileDevice(this HttpRequestBase request)
{

    bool isMobile = request.Browser.IsMobileDevice;
    string userAgent = request.UserAgent.ToLowerInvariant();

    isMobile = isMobile 
            || (userAgent.Contains("iphone")
            || userAgent.Contains("blackberry")
            || userAgent.Contains("mobile")
            || userAgent.Contains("windows ce")
            || userAgent.Contains("opera mini")
            || userAgent.Contains("palm")
            || userAgent.Contains("fennec")
            || userAgent.Contains("adobeair")
            || userAgent.Contains("ripple")
        );
    return isMobile;

}
```

usage in controller:

```
if (Request.IsSupportedMobileDevice()){...}
```

this nuget template is actually very useful, well worth having a look at. see:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9df9c61c-4d90-43e5-9aa1-a58786b7a1e4?SRC=VSIDE

this template actually functions by creating a viewengine override when it detects a mobile device on the server side, thereby, allowing for mobile specific views to be rendered for mobile devices. i have to say, it works pretty well so far in my brief tests.

**[edit]** - for the iphone, the userAgent produced is:

```
mozilla/5.0 (iphone; u; cpu iphone os 4_0 like mac os x; en-us) applewebkit/532.9 (khtml, like gecko) version/4.0.5 mobile/8a293 safari/6531.22.7
```

and for a typical android:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; en-us; HTC_DesireS_S510e Build/GRI40) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

you could therefore parse the userAgent string and locate where the 'version' is located (in the above example - `Android 2.3.3`) as i'm 100% certain that this will be a constant across all userAgent strings. obviously, this would be tedious across a range of 'non-android' devices but hopefully illustrates the potential.

Comment: Thanks This checks for the browser. I need to detect the version of the OS the device is running on.

Comment: socialCircus - gotcha, i'll see if i can shed light on that with further research tmro.. tho, the version is indeed 'contained' within that userAgent string. see my edit above. g'night for now! :)

Answer (score 0):

WURLF http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/dotNet/ can do that. Quite easy to setup and use